# Cloning and serializing a final object

Tags: java, serialization, final, cloning, modifier

When a class is declared as **final**, is it possible to clone or serialize it's objects? Or is this impossible because **final** prevents the extending of subclasses, therefore preventing cloning and serialization from implemented?

Comment: final is not relevant to cloneing. Prevents subclassing not copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final for classes --> You can't extend the class.
Final for objects --> You can't change the reference to the object.

Serializable/cloning--- > These concepts are for objects. You implement an interface to make the object of a perticular class Serializable/Cloneable.

So, yes, when a class is declared as Final, it is possible to Serialize/clone its objects provided you implement the necessary interfaces.

Comment: Sorry, I think I've explained this badly. What I'm trying to get at is: From the point of view of an attacker, is it possible to clone/serialize something when the class was declared as final?

Comment: (From the point of view of an attacker?? ..).. Yes... But the class should have implemented the necessary interfaces...

Comment: OK. So, assuming the necessary interfaces weren't implemented, and the class was declared final, an attacker wouldn't be able to clone/serialize? I'm trying to write a class that cannot be cloned, and I'm wondering if making it final will prevent an attacker from making it clone-able/serializable and cloning/serializing it. Sorry for this mess of a question, and thanks for the replies.

Comment: Making it Final will prevent anyone from extending it. See, If the class doesnt implement Serializable/Cloneable, forget the hacker, even you wont be able to Serialize/clone it directly. He can clone your object explicitly. Final makes no difference. Serializing/cloning are for objects, I repeat, Final for classes means you or anyone else can't extend it. The hacker would want your   object to clone not your class.. got it?

Comment: I think so. If i want to make an object uncloneable, making the class final is irrelevant. I guess I should use something like CloneNotSupportedException?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be not clear on some OOP concepts and their Java implementation.

You extend **classes**, while you serialize and clone **objects**.

There is a [`Singleton` pattern](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=46) that allows only a single object to be created, but that is a whole other story.